# Example of a $C^{1,1}$ surface with constant Gaussian curvate equal to 1, which is not a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

In a [paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/978/art%253A10.1007%252Fs00526-015-0860-z.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs00526-015-0860-z&token2=exp=1472414479~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F978%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs00526-015-0860-z.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs00526-015-0860-z*~hmac=ee95eb9cc257a676419a14ba5c8b93b7bf0473302fdd334b7028288fbc2432df) I'm reading the author talk about the construction of a $C^{1,1}$ surface with constant Gaussian curvature equal to $1$. I do not know what to imagine other then a sphere though, which makes the article difficult to read. So does someone have an example of such surface that is not a sphere?

Comment: Where do they say that their surface has constant Gaussian curvature? I see they construct some surfaces of constant mean curvature. Furthermore, their surfaces have boundary. If I remember correctly, $C^{1,1}$ surfaces of positive curvature in $R^3$ have to be convex (I think, this is due to Borisov). Thus, if you have a $C^{1,1}$ embedded constant  Gaussian curvature closed surface in $R^3$, it has to be a round sphere (by Alexandrov's rigidity theorem). Maybe I misremembering though...

Comment: Yes, indeed, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0370.pdf, Corollary 1.8.

Comment: @MoisheCohen In the actual construction the authors construct a sequence of constant Gaussian curvature surfaces. The final constant mean curvature surfaces is obtained an offset of the limit of this sequence. I did not see how one could obtain something non-spherical using this method. But as you mentioed, the crux is that their surfaces have boundary